# Wordpress: Which file to be edited when executing a command on new post?

Tags: wordpress

I found that intesting answer on how to execute an action on new post.
[Wordpress - Execute Command on New Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181688/wordpress-execute-command-on-new-post/38372930#38372930)

```
<?php
    function my_custom_function(){
        //stuff to do on new post
    }
    add_action('publish_post', 'my_custom_function');
?>
```

My quetsion is: **In what WP file should I add that snippet** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme's functions.php file